# Filtering the package explorer in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, package-explorer

I use Eclipse all the time, and yet I might as well be a newbie. The IDE clearly has many, many features; I guess I get overwhelmed. So this might be a dupe, but I couldn't find the same question being asked anywhere.

What I would like to do is this: I have a project that has a *lot* of packages, most of which are out of my control and I don't really care about. (Basically I'm on a very big team with a large shared codebase.) Can I somehow configure the package explorer so that only the packages I care about are displayed, while still including all those other packages in the project?

For instance, suppose I care about the packages:

```
com.google.MyProject
com.google.MyProject.foo
com.google.MyProject.bar
```

Then I'm imagining a settings menu somewhere where I could add the string "com.google.MyProject*" and the package explorer would then hide all those other packages from the list.